# When using regex in C, \d does not work but [0-9] does

Tags: c, regex

I do not understand why the regex pattern containing the `\d` character class does not work but `[0-9]` does. Character classes, such as `\s` (whitespace characters) and `\w` (word characters), do work. My compiler is gcc (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.3-1ubuntu5) 4.6.3. I am using the C regular expression library.

Why doesn't `\d` work?

Text string:

```
const char *text = "148  apples    5 oranges";
```

For the above text string, this regex does not match:

```
const char *rstr = "^\\d+\\s+\\w+\\s+\\d+\\s+\\w+$";
```

This regex matches when using [0-9] instead of \d:

```
const char *rstr = "^[0-9]+\\s+\\w+\\s+[0-9]+\\s+\\w+$";



#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <regex.h>

#define N_MATCHES  30

//   output from gcc --version: gcc (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.3-1ubuntu5) 4.6.3
//   compile command used:  gcc -o tstc_regex tstc_regex.c

const char *text = "148  apples    5 oranges";
  const char *rstr = "^[0-9]+\\s+\\w+\\s+[0-9]+\\s+\\w+$";    // finds match
//const char *rstr = "^\\d+\\s+\\w+\\s+\\d+\\s+\\w+$";        // does not find match

int main(int argc, char**argv)
{
    regex_t   rgx;
    regmatch_t   matches[N_MATCHES];
    int status;
    status = regcomp(&rgx, rstr, REG_EXTENDED | REG_NEWLINE);
    if (status != 0) {
        fprintf(stdout, "regcomp error: %d\n", status);
        return 1;
    }
    status = regexec(&rgx, text, N_MATCHES, matches, 0);
    if (status == REG_NOMATCH) {
        fprintf(stdout, "regexec result: REG_NOMATCH (%d)\n", status);
    }
    else if (status != 0) {
        fprintf(stdout, "regexec error: %d\n", status);
        return 1;
    }
    else {
        fprintf(stdout, "regexec match found: %d\n", status);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I am guessing a `\d` would match a `d`?

Comment: I haven't found anything that says libc doesn't support [**Shorthand Character Classes**](http://www.regular-expressions.info/shorthand.html).

Comment: One of the nice things about regular expressions is that there are so many flavors to choose from.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The regex flavor you're using is GNU ERE, which is similar to POSIX ERE, but with a few extra features.  Among these are support for the character class shorthands `\s`, `\S`, `\w` and `\W`, but *not* `\d` and `\D`.  You can find more info [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/gnu.html).

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. I overlooked the absence of \d and \D on that page.

Answer (score 4):

Trying either pattern in a strictly POSIX environment will likely end up having no matches; if you want to make the pattern truly POSIX compatible use all bracket expressions:

```
const char *rstr = "^[[:digit:]]+[[:space:]]+[[:alpha:]]+[[:space:]]+[[:digit:]]+[[:space:]]+[[:alpha:]]+$";
```

↳ [POSIX Character_classes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression#Character_classes)

Comment: Quick Note: regular spaces should still work, so the pattern could be shortened perhaps to `^[[:digit:]]+ +[[:alpha:]]+ +[[:digit:]]+ +[[:alpha:]]+$`

Comment: Thanks for this example. When I tried this earlier I used single brackets which seemed to me what the table on [POSIX Character_classes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression#Character_classes) indicated. Also, I would have used a literal space except that I wanted to allow for tabs.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [POSIX regular expression](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009696899/basedefs/xbd_chap09.html) spec:

> An ordinary character is any character in the supported character set, except for the ERE special characters listed in ERE Special Characters. The interpretation of an ordinary character preceded by a backslash ( '\' ) is undefined.

So the only characters that can legally follow a `\` are:

```
\^    \.    \[    \$    \(    \)    \|
\*    \+    \?    \{    \\
```

all of which match the escaped character literally.  Trying to use any of of the other [PCRE](http://www.pcre.org/) extensions may not work.

Comment: @TomKarzes: [glibc supports `\s` and `\w` but not `\d`](https://github.com/bminor/glibc/blob/2a69f853c03034c2e383e0f9c35b5402ce8b5473/posix/regcomp.c#L1787-L1910). Mystery solved. Anyway it's still non-standard syntax.

Comment: @TomKarzes: `REG_EXTENDED` enables extended regular expression (ERE), which is what I was quoting above.  Of course any particular implementation can extend things to provide any sematics for anything the spec says is undefined.

Comment: Alan Moore pointed out that it looks like OP is getting the [GNU ERE extensions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/gnu.html), which include `\w` and `\s` but not `\d`.

Answer (score 1):

\d is a perl and vim character class.

Use instead:

```
 const char *rstr = "^[[:digit:]]+\\s+\\w+\\s+[[:digit:]]+\\s+\\w+$";
```